# Is it possible to launch a program in a specific language?

Tags: macos, software, internationalization, language

I'm a developer, and my primary language is French, so I use Mac OS X in French. However, I need on a regular basis to open an application in English to do support.

Right now I'm going to the International System Preferences and I put English above in the languages list, then I open the app I need to run in English. When I'm done, I switch it back to French.

This is an annoying process. Is there something else I can use, like a command-line program, to launch an application in a specific language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a freeware, [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/), to launch a single application with a different languages.

it's really simple and work amazingly.

Comment: Under the hood, it just launches the program with a `-AppleLanguages (French)` switch, which is what I really needed. Thank you!

Comment: This app seems to be unavailable now. Alternative: App Language Chooser from  MAS https://apps.apple.com/de/app/app-language-chooser/id451732904

Answer (score 73):

You can change the language inside the preferences file of the application :

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit AppleLanguages '("en-US")'
```

Or just run **once** one application with another language :

```
/Applications/iCal.app/Contents/MacOS/iCal -AppleLanguages '(de)'
```

---

To determine the bundle identifier, run

```
mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier /Applications/Mail.app
```

or directly in one command:

```
defaults write $(mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -raw /Applications/Mail.app) AppleLanguages '("en-UK")'
```

(via [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/46301))

Comment: Interesting. The direct "program-call"-approach works for Excel, but not for Numbers. With Numbers you have to change language in the preference file. (The first example above).

Comment: This preference does not work anymore on 10.11. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: It just worked for me on 10.11, no problem here.

Comment: Worked for me on High Sierra (10.13) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the app, Press Command + I and if there are other languages they will show up in the info page. Just untick all except the language you want

Comment: This no longer work in Snow Leopard.

Comment: In Safari on Mojave, it is email shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Chrome do this:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleLanguages '("en-US")'
```

Comment: For Compressor is com.apple.Compressor

Answer (score 0):

I also found this to work:

```
bash-3.2$ LANG=de.UTF-8
bash-3.2$ /Applications/MuseScore\ 3.app/Contents/MacOS/mscore
```

[image: German menu]

Answer (score -2):

In the Finder, get info on the application. There are languages here, and you can choose. Alas, this seems to have disappeared in Snow Leopard.

Comment: How does this differ from @Avi's answer made 3 years ago?