# iOS 5 change AppStore language

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, language

After upgrading to iOS 5 my AppStore language changed to German. Referring to [that quesiton](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/how-to-change-the-language-of-itunes-and-the-app-store) it is possible to change the language by selecting the country in iTunes like it is described in this [apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2242).

My problem is the following : I have a Swiss AppStore account, as you may know Switzerland has many official languages (German, French, Italian, ...) that why a Swiss AppStore account could be in German, French or English as default language.

Before upgrading to iOS 5, the AppStore language was in English as I want it.

I've tried the solution given by the [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2242). But even doing so, you can only select the country but not the language (German is the first language in Switzerland, that's why it falls back to german). By the way, when I go to the iTunes store the language is also German.

I have tried to set English as default language in the following places :

1. iOS's language in ENG
2. iCloud.com account in ENG
3. MacOSX Lion's language where I have my iTunes in also ENG

Where can I specify the language so the AppStore & iTunes Store language will be in english ?

Comment: Try logging out of the store, rebooting the device, and then logging back in.

Comment: Nope, it didn't worked. Still in German

Comment: I thought all Swiss citizens would speak German :)

Comment: Same issue ...
After migration to iOS 5.0 the AppStore, iTunes and Reminders apps are now localized in German (I'm Swiss but would like the applications to be localized in English) did you find any solution?

Comment: @Studer No and even if everybody would, Apple could come over the closed US mentality and realise that not every country is as the USA. As a native Italian speaking Swiss citizen I found really stupid that I need an Italian account to watch moves in Italian (the Swiss store offers just a small bunch of them). Apple.ch is also only available in DE/FR ... No comment

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> General -> International -> Language -> Make sure it's set to English.

If this doesn't work, SYNC to your computer and see if it goes back.

Comment: The language of the system is ignored by the iTunes and App Stores on iOS