# How can i change StarDict dictionary language?

Tags: dictionary

How can i change [StarDict](http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/downloads/detail?name=StarDict-3.0.1-MacOSX.zip&can=2&q=) dictionary language?

I want to set it to English.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a freeware, [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/), to launch an app in a different language.

Or, you check another thread for more detail: [Is it possible to launch a program in a specific language?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-program-in-a-specific-language)

Comment: I launched StarDict with Language Switcher tool but StarDict not open with English language. I check more detail link. I still could not solve my problem.