# How to run an application in a different language?

Tags: macos, settings, internationalization

I have my Mac OS X Yosemite system configured in spanish, but I have an app with a horrible spanish translation, and I would like to run it (and just this app) in english. How could I do that?

Comment: On what device? And maybe in settings there is an option to set another language...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to tell. It's a Mac OS X Yosemite system. I edited the question. And no, the app itself has no option to set the language.

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

So... there is two ways: change the main system language for some time or use this freeware, [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/), which helps to launch single applications with a different language. Also you can try this variant - [App Language Chooser](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/app-language-chooser/id451732904?mt=12&affId=1864973&ign-mpt=uo%3D4).

Answer (score 1):

You may try to move translation files out of application bundle.
First make a copy of Your app (just in case). Then go to the **Resources** folder inside this app-copy (right click -> show package content -> enter **Content** -> enter **Resources**). Here You'll probably find directory called like: **es_ES.lproj**/**es_lproj**/**es_MX.lproj** (or similar) - delete this dir. Launch this app-copy and check the language.

---

**This is a bit overkill** since You can use `-AppleLanguages` switch. Good answers in: [Is it possible to launch a program in a specific language?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-program-in-a-specific-language)